# Making a rig to stretch around the mouth for animation

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I don't want to use a shape key for the rig.  I want to make a rig to make a stretchy, flexible mouth. I want to learn how to do it like the picture below, but I'm a beginner and don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Check Level Pixel Level tutorials, like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG-xHq-8cmc.

Comment: For such a toon character try *Bendy Bones* (*B-Bones*). They are flexible like curves but only work in Blender (not for game engines). [Here](https://youtu.be/-MgU7qOkufU) is a short video on how to set up the control bones (handles) for a single b-bone. And [here](https://youtu.be/5zmWmJLfspg) is a mouth rig with b-bones.